# How to convert the string to integer in jinja?

Tags: python, string, templates, flask, jinja2

I am trying to subtract the lunch time if it is greater than 12 but got this error "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'". How can I convert the lunch time to integer in jinja template:  lunch time returns 14:34 as a string

```
        {% if  today.lunch_time[:2] >12 %}
            <p>Lunch Time : {{ today.lunch_time[:2] - 12}} PM</p>
        {% else %}
            <p>Lunch Time : {{ today.lunch_time}} AM</p>
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: If you're using 24-hour time, then you can just say `if today.lunch_time > "12:00"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert string to integer by '|int'.

Solution:

```
{% if  today.lunch_time[:2]|int >12 %}
    <p>Lunch Time : {{ today.lunch_time[:2]|int - 12}} PM</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Lunch Time : {{ today.lunch_time}} AM</p>
{% endif %}
```